# body max-height in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have a problem with max-height in Firefox.

I build a short Code Example to show the problem. Please open this example in Chrome and in Firefox. The behaviour in Firefox isn't the same as in chrome.

```js
$(function() {

 setTimeout(function() {
  $('body').css("max-height", $('body').height() - 100);
 }, 250);

});
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: red;
}

#background-gradient{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 1;
}

#page-wrapper{
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
    z-index: 2;
}

p{
    margin-top: 0;
}

p:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="background-gradient"></div>
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam auctor facilisis ligula vestibulum fermentum. Curabitur quis imperdiet diam, quis semper velit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum sollicitudin accumsan felis, eu lacinia sapien rutrum at. Quisque vel neque non metus viverra lobortis id quis quam. Vivamus hendrerit viverra nisi, at venenatis ipsum fermentum vel. Morbi viverra velit nunc, ac facilisis lectus sodales ac. Donec eleifend tortor nec lectus tristique lacinia. Integer in tellus ut enim faucibus varius. Suspendisse sit amet orci sed ante gravida condimentum.</p>
    <p>Sed elit odio, tincidunt ac felis fringilla, volutpat imperdiet lorem. Nam rhoncus magna id magna commodo rhoncus. Integer varius placerat velit quis vulputate. Suspendisse accumsan neque ante, in feugiat odio efficitur ut. Morbi euismod viverra rhoncus. Fusce dignissim dapibus est at egestas. Integer pretium cursus tempor. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
    <p>Maecenas vel lobortis ligula. Nam id pulvinar lorem. Aenean tristique dolor eget imperdiet tristique. Duis fringilla, libero et fringilla vulputate, turpis felis tristique augue, non porta nunc est quis dui. Sed imperdiet purus ex, quis faucibus nisl fermentum vitae. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis facilisis, eros at feugiat mollis, libero quam convallis dui, at lacinia metus libero eget enim. Nunc vehicula, dui vitae tempor eleifend, ante augue scelerisque ante, vitae sagittis risus massa sit amet nisi. In imperdiet rhoncus augue, sit amet vehicula erat ultrices non. Nunc tempus in nunc a congue.</p>
    <p>Vestibulum eu auctor mi, id sagittis magna. Proin sed condimentum dolor. Etiam commodo orci nunc, eget laoreet elit blandit sed. Nam magna leo, consectetur ut molestie in, tristique sit amet orci. Donec in vehicula est. Praesent elementum faucibus nisl non fringilla. Fusce fermentum sit amet neque a convallis. Fusce a ultricies est, eget iaculis felis. Vivamus ut ante sed ligula accumsan ultricies. Mauris id est ut lacus imperdiet iaculis eget id nunc.</p>
    <p>Proin dignissim augue suscipit diam porttitor dapibus. Maecenas vel iaculis sem. Proin ut rhoncus mi. Aliquam ultrices mauris et velit lobortis aliquet. Donec quis commodo odio. Nullam nec lectus orci. Nunc id risus odio. Proin maximus odio in nibh dignissim, ut tincidunt est volutpat. Integer mollis maximus varius. Quisque dignissim lorem eu nibh vulputate gravida. Etiam accumsan lectus sit amet tortor tincidunt elementum. Nulla leo nisi, egestas ac imperdiet sit amet, sodales et urna.</p>
    <p>Proin dignissim augue suscipit diam porttitor dapibus. Maecenas vel iaculis sem. Proin ut rhoncus mi. Aliquam ultrices mauris et velit lobortis aliquet. Donec quis commodo odio. Nullam nec lectus orci. Nunc id risus odio. Proin maximus odio in nibh dignissim, ut tincidunt est volutpat. Integer mollis maximus varius. Quisque dignissim lorem eu nibh vulputate gravida. Etiam accumsan lectus sit amet tortor tincidunt elementum. Nulla leo nisi, egestas ac imperdiet sit amet, sodales et urna.</p>
    <p>Proin dignissim augue suscipit diam porttitor dapibus. Maecenas vel iaculis sem. Proin ut rhoncus mi. Aliquam ultrices mauris et velit lobortis aliquet. Donec quis commodo odio. Nullam nec lectus orci. Nunc id risus odio. Proin maximus odio in nibh dignissim, ut tincidunt est volutpat. Integer mollis maximus varius. Quisque dignissim lorem eu nibh vulputate gravida. Etiam accumsan lectus sit amet tortor tincidunt elementum. Nulla leo nisi, egestas ac imperdiet sit amet, sodales et urna.</p>
</div>
```

What I want to do is: remove the 100px gap on the end of the page. (which is only visible in Firefox).

Off course, I know that I can place the div #background-gradient absolute - which would remove this problem. But this is just an example. When using position: absolute, I will get an background flickering in IE, so I have to do it this way. More Details on this Bug: [background-flickering with position absolute/fixed in IE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/9567fc32-016e-48e9-86e2-5fe51fd67402/new-bug-in-ie11-scrolling-positionfixed-backgroundimage-elements-jitters-badly?forum=iewebdevelopment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `margin-top:-100px` instead of `top:-100px`

If you read the [documentation about `position:relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values) it states:

> **relative**
>   This keyword lays out all elements **as though the element were not positioned, and then adjust the element's position, without changing layout (and thus leaving a gap for the element where it would have been had it not been positioned)**. The effect of position:relative on table-*-group, table-row, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: red;
}

#background-gradient{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 1;
}

#page-wrapper{
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -100px;
    z-index: 2;
}

p{
    margin-top: 0;
}

p:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="background-gradient"></div>
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam auctor facilisis ligula vestibulum fermentum. Curabitur quis imperdiet diam, quis semper velit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum sollicitudin accumsan felis, eu lacinia sapien rutrum at. Quisque vel neque non metus viverra lobortis id quis quam. Vivamus hendrerit viverra nisi, at venenatis ipsum fermentum vel. Morbi viverra velit nunc, ac facilisis lectus sodales ac. Donec eleifend tortor nec lectus tristique lacinia. Integer in tellus ut enim faucibus varius. Suspendisse sit amet orci sed ante gravida condimentum.</p>
    <p>Sed elit odio, tincidunt ac felis fringilla, volutpat imperdiet lorem. Nam rhoncus magna id magna commodo rhoncus. Integer varius placerat velit quis vulputate. Suspendisse accumsan neque ante, in feugiat odio efficitur ut. Morbi euismod viverra rhoncus. Fusce dignissim dapibus est at egestas. Integer pretium cursus tempor. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
    <p>Maecenas vel lobortis ligula. Nam id pulvinar lorem. Aenean tristique dolor eget imperdiet tristique. Duis fringilla, libero et fringilla vulputate, turpis felis tristique augue, non porta nunc est quis dui. Sed imperdiet purus ex, quis faucibus nisl fermentum vitae. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis facilisis, eros at feugiat mollis, libero quam convallis dui, at lacinia metus libero eget enim. Nunc vehicula, dui vitae tempor eleifend, ante augue scelerisque ante, vitae sagittis risus massa sit amet nisi. In imperdiet rhoncus augue, sit amet vehicula erat ultrices non. Nunc tempus in nunc a congue.</p>
    <p>Vestibulum eu auctor mi, id sagittis magna. Proin sed condimentum dolor. Etiam commodo orci nunc, eget laoreet elit blandit sed. Nam magna leo, consectetur ut molestie in, tristique sit amet orci. Donec in vehicula est. Praesent elementum faucibus nisl non fringilla. Fusce fermentum sit amet neque a convallis. Fusce a ultricies est, eget iaculis felis. Vivamus ut ante sed ligula accumsan ultricies. Mauris id est ut lacus imperdiet iaculis eget id nunc.</p>
    <p>Proin dignissim augue suscipit diam porttitor dapibus. Maecenas vel iaculis sem. Proin ut rhoncus mi. Aliquam ultrices mauris et velit lobortis aliquet. Donec quis commodo odio. Nullam nec lectus orci. Nunc id risus odio. Proin maximus odio in nibh dignissim, ut tincidunt est volutpat. Integer mollis maximus varius. Quisque dignissim lorem eu nibh vulputate gravida. Etiam accumsan lectus sit amet tortor tincidunt elementum. Nulla leo nisi, egestas ac imperdiet sit amet, sodales et urna.</p>
    <p>Proin dignissim augue suscipit diam porttitor dapibus. Maecenas vel iaculis sem. Proin ut rhoncus mi. Aliquam ultrices mauris et velit lobortis aliquet. Donec quis commodo odio. Nullam nec lectus orci. Nunc id risus odio. Proin maximus odio in nibh dignissim, ut tincidunt est volutpat. Integer mollis maximus varius. Quisque dignissim lorem eu nibh vulputate gravida. Etiam accumsan lectus sit amet tortor tincidunt elementum. Nulla leo nisi, egestas ac imperdiet sit amet, sodales et urna.</p>
    <p>Proin dignissim augue suscipit diam porttitor dapibus. Maecenas vel iaculis sem. Proin ut rhoncus mi. Aliquam ultrices mauris et velit lobortis aliquet. Donec quis commodo odio. Nullam nec lectus orci. Nunc id risus odio. Proin maximus odio in nibh dignissim, ut tincidunt est volutpat. Integer mollis maximus varius. Quisque dignissim lorem eu nibh vulputate gravida. Etiam accumsan lectus sit amet tortor tincidunt elementum. Nulla leo nisi, egestas ac imperdiet sit amet, sodales et urna.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The height is set on the body, the problem is you need to set `overflow:hidden;` to prevent the full child element from showing despite being larger than the parent `body`

```js
$(function() {

 setTimeout(function() {
  $('body').css("max-height", $('body').height() - 100);
 }, 250);

});
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: red;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#background-gradient{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 1;
}

#page-wrapper{
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
    z-index: 2;
}

p{
    margin-top: 0;
}

p:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="background-gradient"></div>
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam auctor facilisis ligula vestibulum fermentum. Curabitur quis imperdiet diam, quis semper velit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum sollicitudin accumsan felis, eu lacinia sapien rutrum at. Quisque vel neque non metus viverra lobortis id quis quam. Vivamus hendrerit viverra nisi, at venenatis ipsum fermentum vel. Morbi viverra velit nunc, ac facilisis lectus sodales ac. Donec eleifend tortor nec lectus tristique lacinia. Integer in tellus ut enim faucibus varius. Suspendisse sit amet orci sed ante gravida condimentum.</p>
    <p>Sed elit odio, tincidunt ac felis fringilla, volutpat imperdiet lorem. Nam rhoncus magna id magna commodo rhoncus. Integer varius placerat velit quis vulputate. Suspendisse accumsan neque ante, in feugiat odio efficitur ut. Morbi euismod viverra rhoncus. Fusce dignissim dapibus est at egestas. Integer pretium cursus tempor. Suspendisse potenti.</p>
    <p>Maecenas vel lobortis ligula. Nam id pulvinar lorem. Aenean tristique dolor eget imperdiet tristique. Duis fringilla, libero et fringilla vulputate, turpis felis tristique augue, non porta nunc est quis dui. Sed imperdiet purus ex, quis faucibus nisl fermentum vitae. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis facilisis, eros at feugiat mollis, libero quam convallis dui, at lacinia metus libero eget enim. Nunc vehicula, dui vitae tempor eleifend, ante augue scelerisque ante, vitae sagittis risus massa sit amet nisi. In imperdiet rhoncus augue, sit amet vehicula erat ultrices non. Nunc tempus in nunc a congue.</p>
    <p>Vestibulum eu auctor mi, id sagittis magna. Proin sed condimentum dolor. Etiam commodo orci nunc, eget laoreet elit blandit sed. Nam magna leo, consectetur ut molestie in, tristique sit amet orci. Donec in vehicula est. Praesent elementum faucibus nisl non fringilla. Fusce fermentum sit amet neque a convallis. Fusce a ultricies est, eget iaculis felis. Vivamus ut ante sed ligula accumsan ultricies. Mauris id est ut lacus imperdiet iaculis eget id nunc.</p>
    <p>Proin dignissim augue suscipit diam porttitor dapibus. Maecenas vel iaculis sem. Proin ut rhoncus mi. Aliquam ultrices mauris et velit lobortis aliquet. Donec quis commodo odio. Nullam nec lectus orci. Nunc id risus odio. Proin maximus odio in nibh dignissim, ut tincidunt est volutpat. Integer mollis maximus varius. Quisque dignissim lorem eu nibh vulputate gravida. Etiam accumsan lectus sit amet tortor tincidunt elementum. Nulla leo nisi, egestas ac imperdiet sit amet, sodales et urna.</p>
    <p>Proin dignissim augue suscipit diam porttitor dapibus. Maecenas vel iaculis sem. Proin ut rhoncus mi. Aliquam ultrices mauris et velit lobortis aliquet. Donec quis commodo odio. Nullam nec lectus orci. Nunc id risus odio. Proin maximus odio in nibh dignissim, ut tincidunt est volutpat. Integer mollis maximus varius. Quisque dignissim lorem eu nibh vulputate gravida. Etiam accumsan lectus sit amet tortor tincidunt elementum. Nulla leo nisi, egestas ac imperdiet sit amet, sodales et urna.</p>
    <p>Proin dignissim augue suscipit diam porttitor dapibus. Maecenas vel iaculis sem. Proin ut rhoncus mi. Aliquam ultrices mauris et velit lobortis aliquet. Donec quis commodo odio. Nullam nec lectus orci. Nunc id risus odio. Proin maximus odio in nibh dignissim, ut tincidunt est volutpat. Integer mollis maximus varius. Quisque dignissim lorem eu nibh vulputate gravida. Etiam accumsan lectus sit amet tortor tincidunt elementum. Nulla leo nisi, egestas ac imperdiet sit amet, sodales et urna.</p>
</div>
```